# How prove this $12hkS(h,k)+12khS(n,k)=h^2+k^2-3hk+1$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

let $h,k$ is positive interger number,and such $gcd(h,k)=1$,let
$$S(h,k)=\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{r}{k}\left(\dfrac{hr}{k}-\left[\dfrac{hr}{k}\right]-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

where $[x]$ is  the largest integer not greater than x

Show that

$$12hkS(h,k)+12khS(k,h)=h^2+k^2-3hk+1$$

My try: since $gcd(h,k)=1$ then
$$\dfrac{r}{k}\left(\dfrac{hr}{k}-\left[\dfrac{hr}{k}\right]-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{hr^2}{k^2}-\dfrac{r}{k}\left[\dfrac{hr}{k}\right]-\dfrac{r}{2k}$$
so
$$\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{hr^2}{k^2}=\dfrac{h}{k^2}\cdot\dfrac{(k-1)k(2k-1)}{6}=\dfrac{h(k-1)(2k-1)}{6k}$$
and
$$\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}-\dfrac{r}{2k}=-\dfrac{1}{2k}\cdot\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}=-\dfrac{k-1}{4}$$
so
$$12hkS(h,k)=2h^2(k-1)(2k-1)-3hk(k-1)-12h\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}r\left[\dfrac{hr}{k}\right]\tag{1}$$
and the same we have
$$12khS(k,h)=2k^2(h-1)(2h-1)-3kh(h-1)-12k\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}r\left[\dfrac{kr}{h}\right]\tag{2}$$
so
$(1)+(2)$
\begin{align*}&\Longrightarrow 12hkS(h,k)+12khS(k,h)\\
&=[2h^2(k-1)(2k-1)+2k^2(h-1)(2h-1)]-3hk[k+h-2]-12h\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}r\left[\dfrac{hr}{k}\right]-2k\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}r\left[\dfrac{kr}{h}\right]
\end{align*}

But I can't,Thank you for you help

Comment: This is known as the reciprocity relation for Dedekind sums. There's a very nice book about them by Rademacher and Grosswald, which has several proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with 
\begin{align}
& 12hkS(h, k)+12khS(k, h) \\
&=2h^2(k-1)(2k-1)+2k^2(h-1)(2h-1)-3hk(k+h-2)-12A 
\end{align}

where
$$A=h\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor}+k\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor}$$
(You have a typo in your last line)

Note that $$\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor=m \Leftrightarrow m \leq \frac{hr}{k} <m+1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{km}{h} \leq r<\frac{k(m+1)}{h}$$

Since $(h, k)=1$, $\frac{km}{h}$ is not an integer for $1 \leq m \leq h-1$, and $\frac{kh}{h}$ is an integer. Thus for $1 \leq m \leq k-2$, $\frac{km}{h} \leq r<\frac{k(m+1)}{h} \Leftrightarrow \left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor +1 \leq r \leq \left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor$. For $m=h-1$, we have $\frac{km}{h} \leq r<\frac{k(m+1)}{h} \Leftrightarrow \left \lfloor \frac{k(h-1)}{h} \right \rfloor +1 \leq r \leq \left \lfloor \frac{kh}{h} \right \rfloor -1$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor} & =\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor} \\
& =\sum_{m=0}^{h-1}{\sum_{\frac{km}{h} \leq r<\frac{k(m+1)}{h}}{rm}} \\
& =\sum_{m=0}^{h-1}{m\sum_{\frac{km}{h} \leq r<\frac{k(m+1)}{h}}{r}} \\
& =\sum_{m=1}^{h-1}{m\sum_{\frac{km}{h} \leq r<\frac{k(m+1)}{h}}{r}} \\
& =\sum_{m=1}^{h-2}{m\sum_{r=\left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor +1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor}{r}}+(h-1)\sum_{r=\left \lfloor \frac{k(h-1)}{h} \right \rfloor +1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{kh}{h} \right \rfloor-1}{r} \\
& =\sum_{m=1}^{h-2}{m\sum_{r=\left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor +1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor}{r}}+(h-1)\sum_{r=\left \lfloor \frac{k(h-1)}{h} \right \rfloor +1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{kh}{h} \right \rfloor}{r}-(h-1)\frac{kh}{h} \\
& =\sum_{m=1}^{h-1}{m\sum_{r=\left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor +1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor}{r}}-(h-1)k\\
& =\sum_{m=1}^{h-1}{m\frac{\left(\left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor \right) \left(\left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right  \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor +1 \right)}{2}}-(h-1)k \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{h-1}{m\left( \left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor^2 - \left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor^2 \right)} \\
& +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{h-1}{m\left( \left \lfloor \frac{k(m+1)}{h} \right \rfloor -\left \lfloor \frac{km}{h} \right \rfloor \right)}-(h-1)k \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(-\left \lfloor \frac{k}{h} \right \rfloor^2+(h-1)\left \lfloor \frac{kh}{h} \right \rfloor^2+\sum_{r=2}^{h-1}{((r-1)-r)\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2} \right) \\
& +\frac{1}{2}\left(-\left \lfloor \frac{k}{h} \right \rfloor+(h-1)\left \lfloor \frac{kh}{h} \right \rfloor+\sum_{r=2}^{h-1}{((r-1)-r)\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} \right)-(h-1)k \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \left((h-1)k(k-1)-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor}-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2} \right)
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align}
A& =h\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor}+k\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} \\
& =\frac{h}{2} \left((h-1)k(k-1)-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor}-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2} \right)+k\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} \\
& =\frac{h(h-1)k(k-1)}{2}-\frac{h}{2}\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor}-\frac{h}{2}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2}-\frac{2k}{h}\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} \right) \\
& =\frac{h(h-1)k(k-1)}{2}-\frac{h}{2}B-\frac{h}{2}C
\end{align}

where 
$$B=\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor}$$
$$C=\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2}-\frac{2k}{h}\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} $$

\begin{align}
B& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\frac{kr}{h}-\left\{\frac{kr}{h}\right\}} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\frac{kr}{h}}-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left\{\frac{kr}{h}\right \}} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\frac{kr}{h}}-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\frac{r}{h}} \; \text{since $(h, k)=1$, $kr$ takes on all nonzero values $\pmod{h}$} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\frac{(k-1)r}{h}} \\
& =\frac{k-1}{h}\frac{(h-1)h}{2} \\
& =\frac{(k-1)(h-1)}{2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
C& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2}-\frac{2k}{h}\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left(\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor^2-\frac{2kr}{h}\left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor \right)} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left( \left(\frac{kr}{h}- \left \lfloor \frac{kr}{h} \right \rfloor \right)^2 -\left( \frac{kr}{h} \right)^2 \right)} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left\{\frac{kr}{h}\right \}^2}-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left( \frac{kr}{h} \right)^2} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left(\frac{r}{h}\right)^2}-\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{\left( \frac{kr}{h} \right)^2} \; \text{since $(h, k)=1$, $kr$ takes on all nonzero values $\pmod{h}$} \\
& =\frac{1-k^2}{h^2}\sum_{r=1}^{h-1}{r^2} \\
& =\frac{1-k^2}{h^2}\frac{(h-1)h(2h-1)}{6} \\
& =\frac{(1-k^2)(h-1)(2h-1)}{6h}
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align}
A& =\frac{h(h-1)k(k-1)}{2}-\frac{h}{2}B-\frac{h}{2}C \\
& =\frac{h(h-1)k(k-1)}{2}-\frac{h}{2}\frac{(k-1)(h-1)}{2}-\frac{h}{2}\frac{(1-k^2)(h-1)(2h-1)}{6h} \\
& =\frac{h(h-1)k(k-1)}{2}-\frac{(k-1)h(h-1)}{4}-\frac{(1-k^2)(h-1)(2h-1)}{12} \\
&=\frac{(h-1)(k-1)}{12}\left(6hk-3h+(k+1)(2h-1) \right) \\
&=\frac{(h-1)(k-1)(8hk-h-k-1)}{12}
\end{align}

Finally, we have

\begin{align}
& 12hkS(h, k)+12khS(k, h) \\
& =2h^2(k-1)(2k-1)+2k^2(h-1)(2h-1)-3hk(k+h-2)-12A \\
& =2h^2(k-1)(2k-1)+2k^2(h-1)(2h-1)-3hk(k+h-2) \\
& -(h-1)(k-1)(8hk-h-k-1) \\
& = \text{(after simplification)} h^2+k^2-3hk+1
\end{align}